# generating xml file from .NET software and automatically insert into mysql database if not exist

Tags: php, .net, xml, codeigniter

My question is bit long. I have the oldest student management software and now i want to install new cloud based SMS in the school where i want to generate the student information in XML format from the my old version .NET school management system and automatically sync all the data into mySQL database for my new cloud based SMS which was made using PHP (codeigniter framework). The condition for sync data will be the if the data already exist then don't insert into mysql. How can i achieve that any good suggestions will be very helpful for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a similar question about building XML in .NET

[How can I build XML in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284324/how-can-i-build-xml-in-c)

and here a similar question about how to insert records in database if not exist

[Adding records in vb.net and Checking if records exist using elseif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20649548/adding-records-in-vb-net-and-checking-if-records-exist-using-elseif)

Good luck.